# Complex roots for $ (\bar z + i)^6 = -1 $

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

> Solve:$$
> (\bar z + i)^6 = -1
> $$

I solve this as $z= 0$ only .

But I searched in an online solver and got 
$z=0, z=2i, z=-\sqrt3/2+1/2\,i$.

Comment: Your question is...? Do you want us to solve it for you, and show how it is done? How did you "Solve" to $z=0$? Please provide some context!

Comment: Hi Islam.  As you can see, a few people (such as Rohan most recently) have edited your question to make it more readable.  In the future, it would be helpful if you could format your math properly, as is explained thoroughly [at this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360).  While it is great that you have outlined your attempt so far, it would have been nice if you could have made your question explicit (for example, you could have said "how can I find the other solutions?").

Comment: Finally, as Ove indicates above, a little bit more context (how did you find $z = 0$ exactly?  Is there a certain approach you wanted to use here?) would have been helpful.

Comment: Oh sorry I am truly new to complex !

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Let $w=\bar z+i$ and solve $w^6=-1$.

The six solutions of $w^6=-1$ are solutions of $w^{12}=1$ but not of $w^6=1$ and so are the $12$-th roots of unity that are not $6$-th roots of unity.

Comment: Then w^6=-1 would it be w=(-1)^1/6 = i?

Answer (score 1):

$$(\bar z + i)^6 = -1\Longleftrightarrow ( z - i)^6 = -1 \Longleftrightarrow z= i +x_k$$

Where $$x_k = e^{\frac{i\pi}{6}+\frac{2ik\pi}{6}}~~k=0,1,....5$$

Comment: Can explain to me each step i am truly new to complex

Comment: @IslamAlshawish $Z^6=-1\implies  Z=e^{\frac{i\pi}{6}+\frac{2ik\pi}{6}}~~k=0,1,....5$ now set $Z= z-i$ then....

Comment: But why (conjz +i)=(z-i)?

Comment: @IslamAlshawish you read your lecture note or just aplly the definition of complex conjugate

Comment: I need to learn how to deal with conjugate

Answer (score 1):

As $$-1 = cos((2k + 1)\pi) + isin((2k + 1)\pi)$$  where $k$ is an integer. By de Moivre's theorem we can write $$ -1  = e^{{i\pi}+ i2k\pi} $$Thus your equation becomes $$(\bar z + i)^6 = -1 $$ $$(z - i)^6 = -1 = e^{{i\pi}+ i2k\pi} $$ $$ z = i + e^{\frac{i\pi}{6}+\frac{i 2k\pi}{6}}$$ you will get all the solution for different values for $k$ by using de Moivre's theorem, but no need to check for value other than $k=0,1,....5$ since $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are periodic functions.

Comment: What if I'd like the solution to be the values on the left half plane only without even y axis?

Comment: Then use only those values of k such that argument of z lies in 2nd or 3rd quadrant only.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the answer of @lhf because $-1=e^{i(\pi+2k\pi)}$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z$ then $$w^6=-1\iff w=(e^{i(\pi+2k\pi)})^{1/6}=e^{i\frac{\pi+2k\pi}6},\quad\forall k\in\Bbb Z$$

Because the complex exponential is $i2\pi$ periodic then it is enough to consider the solutions such that $\frac{\pi+2k\pi}6\in(-\pi,\pi]$ because any other solution outside of this interval will be repeated.

Then we find solutions for $k=-3,-2,-1,0,1,2$. By last if $w=\bar z+i$ then $z=\bar w+i$.